# Angular forms (reactive forms) and NgRx

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

Now far in the past I started to learn NgRx and can't solve an issue like that. 
PLEASE give me a CLEAR example how we can do it because I dont have an idea. There is an ISSUE.  1. I have a parent component with 2 buttons. 2. I have 2 children each with 1 input field. 3. I fill the value in first child component, IT'S a case to switch to a second children. 4. I fill the input of the second and want to go back to the first component and to see the value that I have already inputed. 5. In case that we have 2 values in two inputs we CAN submit the submit button at footer component and to render our value in the center of the screen.

Comment: Break down the question and provide the code you have tried so far..

Comment: I have tried 4 examples of different code and no one has worked so I deleted all. But if you will send me some independent example or video that's will great

Comment: You question isnt clear enough

Comment: 1. I have a parent component with 2 buttons. 2. I have 2 children each with 1 input field. 3. I fill the value in first child component, IT'S a case to switch to a second children. 4. I fill the input of the second and want to go back to the first component and to see the value that I have already inputed. 5. In case that we have 2 values in two inputs we CAN submit the submit button at footer component and to render our value in the center of the screen.

Comment: @IliaMilshtein edit your question to include this information